# Read a file having a dynamically name everytime it is generated in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, npm, cypress, e2e-testing

As I'm new to Cypress, I've to write a test case to check whether the file is downloaded or not, I've been through multiple posts related to the similar test case, but all of them having the test case to read a file which has a static name, in my case I've to read a file which is downloaded after clicking the download button and every time the file is downloaded it will have a dynamic name, though the filename has some patterns (ex. filename starts with a fixed set of characters).

I wanted to achieve something like this in cypress,

`cy.readFile('C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\${Regular expression to match the filename pattern}`

Below is the snippet from cy.task() documentation, in which the task is to read a file exists or not, but the if the filename is not static then how it is possible to achieve

```
// in plugins/index.js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    readFileMaybe (filename) {
      if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
        return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')
      }

      return null
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there are any file-read or file-exists commands that can take a regular expression.

You can read the `C:\Users\UserName\Downloads` folder before and after the download, and take the diff.

**cypress.json**

```js
{
  "downloadsFolder": "C:\Users\UserName\Downloads"
}
```

**plugins**

```js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    filesInDownload (folderName) {
      return fs.readdirSync(folderName)
    }
  })
  return config
}
```

**Test**

```js
const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')

cy.task('filesInDownload', downloadsFolder).then(files1 => {

  // download

  cy.task('filesInDownload', downloadsFolder).then(files2 => {
    let difference = files2.filter(x => !files1.includes(x));
    expect(difference.length).to.be.gt(0)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to achieve something like this in cypress,

```
cy.readFile('C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\${Regular expression to match the filename pattern}
```

=>
I think you need to workaround these cases as:

1. delete all in the folder
2. `using cy.readfile from readdirSync`

Ex:

```
const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')

cy.task('filesInDownload', downloadsFolder).then(files1 => {

  cy.readFile('downloadsFolder' + '/' + files[0]).contains(content)

})
```